# can't able to install consoletvs/charts on laravel

Tags: laravel, charts, composer-php

is there anyone has come across with this problem before. I want to install that package using PHP composer but every time I run composer update.... its always ran into this problem. I'm using laravel 6.x. I am planning to do an upgrade on all the dependencies required but I'm hesitate as I don't want to end up causing more errors to my application. I appreciate the help I can get.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install consoletvs/charts 7.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install consoletvs/charts 7.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install consoletvs/charts 7.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install consoletvs/charts 7.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.20
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.18.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.17.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.17.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.15.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.15.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.14.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.13.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.13.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.12.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.11.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.10.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.10.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.8.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.6.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.4.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.4.0
```

Comment: Try `composer require consoletvs/charts ^6`. Looks like you're trying to install a version that's made for Laravel 7 into a Laravel 6 app.

Comment: Try that and I get this
 **date
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.**

Comment: Please share more details - what's the exact command you are executing, and which other packages are present in `composer.json`?

Comment: I have the following on my composer.json
`        "php": "^7.2",
        "bavix/laravel-admin-leaflet": "^1.0",
        "consoletvs/charts": "^6",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0",
        "infyomlabs/adminlte-templates": "6.0.x-dev",
        "infyomlabs/laravel-generator": "6.0.x-dev",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.0",
        "prettus/l5-repository": "^2.6",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"`

Answer (score 3):

I use this in a composer.json

```
"consoletvs/charts": "^6",
```

and I ran the following to solve this issue.

```
composer self-update
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use composer require consoletvs/charts so that it installs the package compatible with your laravel version